# oracle sqlplus no username and database

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I installed oracle sqlplus and instant client on mac os using this tutorial: https://tomeuwork.wordpress.com/2014/05/12/how-to-install-oracle-sqlplus-and-oracle-client-in-mac-os/comment-page-1/

I can now open sqlplus in the terminal by typing sqlplus but it asks me for username and password.

I researched on the net that these should be created during installation however when I done it, it didn't prompt me and in the tutorial it doesn't mention it. It only says you should now be able to connect using `$ sqlplus username/password@database` but I don't have a username, password, nor a database ready.

How do I do this?

I want to set everything up so I can create a database and create tables etc using sqlplus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQLplus is a command line client for the Oracle database system and the Instant Client is a slim driver from accessing it. So you haven't installed the Oracle database (server) yet, just the client.

The Oracle server does not run on Mac OS X. You will need to install it on a machine with a different operation system.

**Update**

Using SQLplus you can connect to the Oracle server at your university (unless they have specifically guarded against it). You will need some information to connect:

- Host name
- Port number
- SID or service name
- username
- password

Then you can connect using the following command:

```
sqlplus username@host:port/service
```

Or:

```
sqlplus username@'(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=hostname)(PORT=port))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=sid)(SERVER=dedicated)))'
```

SQL Developer from Oracle is a free alternative client with a UI that will make it easier to connect to the database and do your assignment. It requires the same information though.

Comment: Do i have to install Oracle database system myself? I need it for my university assignment and i can do it on the machines there, is there a way I can connect from my mac to there?